# How redirect my saml2-client to home page when i authenticate with local SP and IDP Saml2

Tags: java, saml-2.0, idp, spring-security-saml2

I try to authenticate an application with an SP and IDP local but when I try from the same server(IDP) the response is ok but when I try from other application the response redirect show an error

This is the error:

[image]

This is my IDP code when redirect the response:

```
@Override
protected ServiceProviderMetadata getTargetProvider(HttpServletRequest request) {
    IdentityProviderService provider = getProvisioning().getHostedProvider();
    String param = request.getParameter("SAMLRequest");
    AuthenticationRequest authn =
            provider.fromXml(
                    param,
                    true,
                    HttpMethod.GET.name().equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()),
                    AuthenticationRequest.class
            );
    provider.validate(authn);
    return provider.getRemoteProvider(authn);
}
```

The client are in the 8080 port and sp 8082 and idp 8081

this is my application.yml:

[image]

How i do for redirect to 8080/home in the client application?
When call from http://localhost:8080 this field is null in the getTargetProvider() method:
String param = request.getParameter("SAMLRequest");

Answer (score 0):

only put the default-success-url: https://localhost:8443/login into the application.yml and works